# Inserting executable javascript code from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In C I'm accustomed to do something like:

```
//MyHeaderFile.h
#define MY_CONSTANT 34


//MyMainFile.c
#include MyHeaderFile.h
int num = MY_CONSTANT;
```

I want do something in an html document like:

```
//MyJS.js
#define MY_SCRIPT <script>some javascript stuff </script> 

//MyHTML.html
<html>
MY_SCRIPT
</html>
```

This html would execute whatever script code was defined as MY_SCRIPT.  Basically What I want is to have multiple .html files reference the javascript code, all of them executing the same code defined in the .js file.  It would just be nice to be able to change the code in the .js file once and have it affect all of the html files at once.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. html doesn't "execute", 2. neither HTML nor javascript know what #define is, 3. javascript belongs in a script tag, not an HTML tag, 4. to "insert" executable javascript code in an HTML file, `<script src="scriptfile.js"></script>` - this is HTML 101 stuff!!!

Comment: 1. I know it doesnt execute. 2. I know neither knows what #define is(I'm asking for an equivalent) 3. The MY_SCRIPT "macro" contains the script tag 4.  Inserting the javascript file like that does not automatically execute the code in the .js file

Comment: 4. yes it does, that's how browsers have worked since dinosaurs roamed the plains my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference your JS file in a script element as such

```
<script src="(LOCATION OF JS FILE)"></script>
```

This will cause the Javascript code to execute when the element loads.

Check out this tutorial for more info

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can have many files as you want. For example in a file called "header.js" you can put this:

```
var MY_CONSTANT = 34;
```

And in your html file simply put the reference to that file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //You can use MY_CONSTANT here
    var myNumber = MY_CONSTANT;
</script>
```

You can have many files as you want, but be sure to put the header.js before another scripts